# Как в bootstrap сделать группированный но не склеянный toggle button?

Tags: bootstrap

а именно buttons-radio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кнопки связываются по data-toggle, а стиль btn-group можно просто убрать

```
<div data-toggle="buttons-radio">
    <button type="button" class="btn">Left</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn active">Middle</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn">Right</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает :). А как сделать чтобы одна кнопка была по умолчанию в нажатом состояний?

Comment: Добавить класс active к нужной кнопке, в примере по умолчанию Middle